# android:how to change AlertDilog Box Background Colour?

Tags: android, background-color, android-alertdialog

I want to Change `AlertDialog` Color instead of default `Grey` Color i want to have my cutom color for eg(`blue` Color).
So please provide me information to Change the color

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you can use custom layout for the dialog and then you can inflate that custom xml for that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This is default alertdialog you can't change anything. For any new look you must create a custom dialog

[Follow this link to making custom dialog](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example)